# Match one column with another data frame column and paste value from second data - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames one contains the data second contains codes and their decode values. i want to match df1[code] with df2[code] and paste df2[value] in df1.
it should be noted that my second data frame contains code and values once, its basically a sheet of codes and values but in first data frame the codes are repeating so the values column which will be pasted should represent the value every time when the code appears in df1[code] column.

| df1[code] | df2[code] | df2[value] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | 000 | Three |
| 235 | 234 | Two |
| 238 | 238 | Four |
| 337 | 235 | Five |

i need as following:

| df1[code] | df1[value] |
| --- | --- |
| 234 | Two |
| 235 | Five |
| 238 | Four |
| 337 | Null |

basically translation of codes in one data frame from second data frame.

Comment: look at merge if you have 2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` , `df1.merge(df2,on='Code')` .

Comment: could you show your attempted codes?

Comment: merge is not working as df1 has many columns so it gives error of datatypes.

Comment: i have tried to convert df2 into dictionary as well . but then the matching doesnt takes place with df1[code] and all printed values are null\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you dataframes are the following ones:

```sh
df1
   code     something  some_number
0   210  SOMETHING_28     0.206017
1   913  SOMETHING_36     0.810195
2   210  SOMETHING_18     0.258638
3  None             a     0.000000
```

```sh
df2
   code     value
0   210  VALUE_01
1   590  VALUE_02
2   614  VALUE_03
3   696  VALUE_04
4   913  VALUE_05
```

Then, you can use `merge`, changing the type of the `code` column, if needed (e.g., if it is a string):

```py
df1.code = df1.code.map(lambda x: np.int64(x) if x else np.nan).astype('Int64')
df2.code = df2.code.astype('Int64')
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='code', how='left')
```

And you get:

```sh
   code     value
0   210  VALUE_01
1   913  VALUE_05
2   210  VALUE_01
3  <NA>       NaN
```

Here the code to create `df1` and `df2` with the same structure as the ones shown in this answer:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

codes = sorted(np.random.randint(1, 1000, 5))
values = [f'VALUE_{x:02.0f}' for x in range(1, len(codes) + 1)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        [c, f'SOMETHING_{np.random.randint(1, 50)}', np.random.random()]
        for c in np.random.choice(codes, 3)
    ],
    columns=['code', 'something', 'some_number']
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=list(zip(codes, values)),
    columns=['code', 'value']
)
```

Comment: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat.. this is the error im getting @Piecot

Comment: You should provide an example of your dataframes (with the actual types of their columns) if they are different from the ones I used here. Maybe you have some nan values somewhere...

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle strings and null values in `code` column of  `df1`

Answer (score 0):

How about use a map-dict:

```
map_dict = dict(zip(df2['code'], df2['value']))
df1['value'] = df1['code'].map(map_dict)
```